# Binding problems with decodepixel xaml uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, bitmapimage

this is my first question in stackoverflow, so excuse me for mistakes..

I am trying to bind a converter to decodepixel property of a bitmap image, to dynamic scale my spritesheet with no luck.
The converter with parameter Animation256 returns a value of 1960(for my screen) but the animation is not working. When i manually set the value to 1960, everything works fine. I know the converter works fine when I bind it to resize Fonts or the width and height of previous rectangle..

Here is the code:

```
<Rectangle
    Width="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource FontKey}, ConverterParameter='Animation256Size'}"
    Height="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource FontKey}, ConverterParameter='Animation256Size'}" >
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top">
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <BitmapImage
                    UriSource="ms-appx:///Animation/spaceship.png"
                    DecodePixelWidth="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource FontKey}, ConverterParameter='Animation256'}"
                    DecodePixelHeight="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource FontKey}, ConverterParameter='Animation256'}"
                    DecodePixelType="Logical" />
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="SpriteSheetOffset" X="0" Y="0" />
            </ImageBrush.Transform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

And the converter

```
public class FontHelper : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "TinyFontSize":
                return (int)((double)value / 34);
            case "MediumFontSize":
                return (int)((double)value / 20);
            case "SmallFontSize":
                return (int)((double)value / 25);
            case "Animation256":
                return (int) ( (double)value * 2.37 * 0.1) * 10;
            case "Animation256Size":
                return ((int)((double)value * 2.37 * 0.1));
            default:
                return 5;// <--- This is never used, but just in case
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // not needed yet
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is "ThisWindow". I have tried your code. 0 value is passing to the converter

Comment: It is the page name, and we ask the ActualHeight of it.(meaning the vertical screen resolution). This value goes in the converter and it is returned. Problem is: binding does not work for the decodepixel !!!.

Comment: I also tried to do it with code, no luck. It seems to me that DecodePixel can accept only a static value... CAN someone confirm this? I think I am losing my time trying to get it to work.